# Integrate Google Maps API v3 into a WordPress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I have searched a lot of solutions for this problem but none worked out for me. I would like to integrate Google Maps into a Wordpress page, without using a plugin and without embedding.

In the head of header.php I attached this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*********&sensor=true"> </script>
```

Then also in header.php I have put this:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

But now I don't know where to put the script:

```
function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.371, -4.136),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDo2uLLlKn3xuYolvd0VNzBujoZ952YywE&sensor=true&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
window.onload = loadScript;
```

If anybody has a solution I would really appreciate it, thanks a lot!

Comment: are you using page.php or else custom template page for a page?

Comment: I am using a custom template page

Comment: so you can put the script on that page, else you can put the script in header or footer also

Comment: Why are you loading the google maps api twice? First in the head as script include and second in the loadScript function. And the initialize function is also attached twice. You don't need the 'onload="initialize()"' if you attach the function with "addDomListener".

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code into a js file and load it after the api script include.
A little bit cleaner code would be:

```
(function () {
    function initMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.371, -4.136),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
}());
```

With this self calling anonymous function you don't introduce globals and encapsulates you code.

Comment: If I create a js file with this code, where should I call it? In the code editor of the custom template page? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Custom page sounds good. You wrote that you have added the script include into the header.php?! If you need only the map on this custom page, then you should include this only on the custom template. Otherwise the google maps api will be loaded on every page.

Comment: I tried putting the whole script and the script include in the text editor of the custom page, but it doesn't work.